# How to get a specific part of a string using Regex after specific occurances?

Tags: regex, go

The regex I have is using Golang: `/([^/]+)$` which basically matches the last part of the string i.e `"try/me"` will match the `me` and return true. How do I make sure it matches the content after 3 `/` slashes and then return match. I.e this should return a match: `/try/me/now/yet` where now is the match (after 3 specific slashes only). The string can contain more slashes but should only return the match after specifically the 3rd one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
^(?:[^/]*/){3}([^/]*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/paikW1/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[^/]*/){3}` - three sequences of any zero or more chars other than `/` and then a `/` char
- `([^/]*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than `/`.